# Copying files from my CD drive drops to 0 bytes/s

Tags: audio, dvd, compact-disc

I recently bought a text book which came with a CD which contains audio files. I need to copy the audio files to my PC but after a few seconds, the speed of the transfer drops to 0 bytes per seconds so I cant finish transferring the files.

My laptop is brand new if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are the audio files?

Comment: As above. If they're not .MP3, .WAV etc... then you may need to 'rip' them. Also, is there enough space on the target drive?

Comment: There are only four reasons I know of that would cause this: the CD is damaged, either physically or there was an error during mastering _(rule out by trying the same from another optical drive)_, the optical drive hardware or SATA cable is at fault _(rule out by trying another CD)_, the partition it's being copied doesn't have enough free space, or there's a permissions issue with the target directory preventing the copy. A DRM issue is possible, but not likely, and I would try @spikey_richie's suggestion.